# How can I create a triggered Automation with ExactTarget's Soap API?

Tags: soap-api, fuel-sdk, automation

I'd like to be able to create an automation in ExactTarget's automation studio that is triggered by the creation of a file with ET's Webservice API. I've managed to create a SOAP request to create an scheduled automation but I can't create a triggered automation.

Anyone can give a full example of how to create a triggered automation and how to specify the folder that will fire the trigger?